# Read XML on LINUX

Tags: c++, xml, linux

I have requirement where we have to read a small XML file on Linux. Our application is in C++ and I like to use any light weight XML library. Please suggest me  the library.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can Try [pugixml](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/) Light-weight, simple and fast XML parser for C++

As a 2nd option look at [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look also at TinyXml (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml). It is extremely lightweight and for this reason it is used also in mobile and game programming. The API is minimal though so you have to evaluate if it fully satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[This xml parser](http://www.applied-mathematics.net/tools/xmlParser.html) is good

Answer (score 0):

There is [xerces-c](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) for that. It's complete, but I don't know if you will find it small enough. Your question is relative to what?

Comment: My requirement is memory related. It should not eat much memory.